# Checking in existing code into a new repo on Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I'm trying to check a new app I created using Visual Studio Code on my local machine into a new repo on Azure DevOps. I'm using Git as my version control.

Could someone point me to an article or give me the steps? The articles I found all point to checking an existing project FROM a repo TO my computer. I need to do it the other way around. FROM my computer TO a new repo on Azure DevOps.

Comment: The repo would generally need to already exist (you can't create repositories from git). Unless you are talking about hitting an Azure DevOps API to create the remote repo first?

Comment: why do you ask this question? its exactly the same as with any other git repo

Answer (score 1):

After committing your changes in your local repo, you can execute the following command in VS Code terminal:

```
git remote add origin https://DevOps.Azure.com/<....>

git remote -v

git push -u origin master
```